# Reference request for facts about bi(co)descent objects

Tags: reference-request, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

I know the following facts are true, but I struggle to find adequate references for them:

1. Let $T$ be a pseudo-monad on a bicategory $\mathcal{C}$, and let $A$, $B$ be pseudo-algebras for $T$. Then, the following descent diagram[image] is a bilimit in $\mathcal{C}$.
2. Let [image] be a bicodescent diagram in $\mathcal{C}$. The object $A$ is a bicolimit of this diagram if and only if the pseudofunctor $H:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathbf{Bicat}$ defined as the bilimit [image] in the bicategory of pseudofunctors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathbf{Bicat}$ is represented by $A$.

Does anyone know where to find them in the litterature?

Answer (score 2):

1. This follows from Lemma 2.3 and Proposition 3.2 of Creurer–Marmolejo–Vitale's [Beck's theorem for pseudo-monads](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902000385), together with fact that the bicategorical Yoneda embedding preserves bilimits.
2. Presumably you mean a pseudofunctor to $\mathbf{Cat}$, rather than $\mathbf{Bicat}$, because you are working with bicategories rather than tricategories? This then follows from the fact that the bicategorical Yoneda embedding creates bilimits, which is a consequence of the [bicategorical Yoneda lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma+for+bicategories).